# Formatting Table MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, format

I have the following code which formats a table on a webpage like this:

http://thepoolscene.com/rooms-new/

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Room Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Map</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td font color=red>" . $row['NameofLocation'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . ", " . $row['City'] . "  " . $row['Province'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" . $row['Address'] . "+" . $row['City'] . "+" . $row['Province'] . "&hl=en'target=“_blank” >Map</a></font></td></tr>" . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

I would like to format the table with some color and space out the columns a little more evenly.  Is there a way to automate the width of each column?  Specifically, it is the phone number and Map field which will remain constant.

Comment: you can use CSS for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```
<th style='width:50%; color:red;'>Room Name</th>
<th style='width:50%; color:red;'>Address</th>
<th style='width:80px; color:red;'>Phone</th>
<th style='width:20px; color:red;'>Map</th>
```